# making Baxter do an action once

Tags: python, ros

I just started working with the rethink robotics baxter.

In their example for responding to button controls they use event handlers (I think).
Example (from gripper_cuff_control.py):

```
self._open_io.state_changed.connect(self._open_action)
```

I want to be able to push a button and move the wrist a set amount, I can currently do that, but it happens twice (once for state_changed -> pushed and once for state_changed -> released)

What is the most elegant way to make it so that the action only happens once on when a button is pushed and released?

Comment: Can you detect the difference or are you able to pass the state to your function?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find documentation on the API, but from [this example](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/baxter_examples/html/gripper__cuff__control_8py_source.html) it looks like the first parameter to the function will tell you whether the button was pressed or released.

```
def _open_action(self, value):
    if value: #button was pressed
        #do stuff here in response to button press
    else: #button was released
        #do stuff here in response to button release
```